# Django: how to display ProductImage from Product model

Tags: django, django-views

```
class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image_path = models.ImageField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
```

in my views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = "catalog/product_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    model = Product
```

**in product_list.html the problem is here**

```
{% if product_list %}           
    {% for product in product_list %}
         <!-- the problem is here -->
         if there is an image show 
         <img src="default" />
         else
         <img src="product.ProductImage.image_path here" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

the problem is in the iteration of the product_list
i tried, productImage = product.[productImage or product_image or is it productimage].first() but it doesn't work

i also tried

```
{% 
                            img = ''
                            try:
                                productImage = product.productimage_set.first() 
                                img = productImage.image_path
                            except ProductImage.DoesNotExist:   
                                img = ''
                                %}
                                <img class="card-img-top" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{product_image.image_path}}" data-holder-rendered="true">
                                {%
                            %}
```

but it just outputs the code block

i also tried this

```
 {% productImage = product.productimage_set.first() %}
```

but it says **'productImage', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `url` attribute of the image.

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {% for product_image in product.productimage_set.all %}
        <image src="{{ product.image_path.url }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how do I access ProductImage from product in the loop? Product can have 0 or many ProductImage

Comment: @HeeroYuy The initial version had the ProductImage as a foreign key to product. hence my original answer. I have updated the answer

Comment: thanks Aswin, I only want to get the first image so i did this `{% product_image = product.productimage_set.first %}` but I get this error
`Invalid block tag on line 28: 'product_image', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

other products have no image so i think i need to add a condition, i'm still very new to python

Comment: To assign a variable inside template, use this: `{% with product.productimage_set.first as product_image %}`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to post the first photo, you do not need the second for loop. Just use:

```
<image src="{{ product.productimage.all.0.image_path.url }}" />
```

Sorry, I'm 3 years late...but in case anyone else stumbles across this.